# HTML Title a[href] jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari-extension

I am creating a Safari Extension which shows the link of the website as a title when there is a mouseover.

I have done this so far

`$("a[href]").mouseover(function() {
   this.html("<title=>");
});`

Basically I want to have when the user puts the mouse over the link it shows what the link is.

For example if the the user puts the mouse over the 'United Kingdom - Adobe' link it should be www.adobe.com/au/

[image]

Here is the inspect element.
[image]

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Here it is.

`$("a[href]").mouseover(function() {
   $(this).attr("title",this);
 });`